# Access SQL query - Percentage of Total calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregation, percentage, iif

In Access SQL, I am attempting what should seem like a simple task in attaining a percentage of total. There are 3 item stores (Sears, kmart & Mktpl) of which in any given week, I wish to calculate their respective percent of total based on balance of sales (all can be obtained using one table - tbl_BUChannelReporting).

For example week 5 dummy numbers - Sears 7000, kmart 2500, mktpl 2000
the following ratios would be returned: sears 61%, kmart 22%, mktpl 17%

I was originally trying to create a sub query and wasn't getting anywhere so I am essentially trying to sum sales on one of the item stores in week 5 divided by the sum of all 3 item store sales in week 5. The following is my query, which is giving me "cannot have aggregate function in expression" error:

```
SELECT FY, FW, Rept_Chnl, BU_NM, Order_Store, Item_Store, CDBL(

SUM(IIF([item_store]="sears", revenue, IIF([item_store]="kmart", revenue, IIF([item_store]="mktpl", revenue,0)))) /

(SUM(IIF([item_store]="sears",revenue,0)+SUM(IIF([item_store]="kmart",revenue,0)+SUM(IIF([item_store]="mktpl",revenue,0)))))) 

 AS Ratios
FROM tbl_BUChannelReporting
WHERE FY = "2017"
AND FW = 5
GROUP BY FY, FW, Rept_Chnl, BU_NM, Order_Store, item_store
```

Thanks all in advance for taking the time. This is my 1st post here and I don't consider myself anything but a newbie anxious to learn from the best and see how this turns out.

Take care!

-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using two derived tables or saved aggregate queries: one that groups on *Item_Store* and the other that does not include *Item_Store* in order to sum the total stores' revenue. All other groupings (*FY*, *FW*, *Rept_Chnl*, *BU_NM*, *Order_Store*) remain in both and used to join the two. Then in outer query, calculate percentage ratio.

```
SELECT i.*, CDbl(i.Store_Revenue / a.Store_Revenue) As Ratios
FROM
  (SELECT t.FY, t.FW, t.Rept_Chnl, t.BU_NM, t.Order_Store, t.Item_Store, 
          SUM(t.Revenue) As Store_Revenue
   FROM tbl_BUChannelReporting t
   WHERE t.FY = '2017' AND t.FW = 5 
   GROUP BY t.FY, t.FW, t.Rept_Chnl, t.BU_NM, t.Order_Store, t.Item_Store) As i
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT t.FY, t.FW, t.Rept_Chnl, t.BU_NM, t.Order_Store 
          SUM(t.Revenue) As Store_Revenue
   FROM tbl_BUChannelReporting t
   WHERE t.FY = '2017' AND t.FW = 5 
   GROUP BY t.FY, t.FW, t.Rept_Chnl, t.BU_NM, t.Order_Store) As a
ON i.FY = a.FY AND i.FW = a.FW AND i.Rept_Chnl = a.Rept_Chnl 
AND i.BU_NM = a.BU_NM AND i.Order_Store = a.Order_Store
```

Or save each above `SELECT` statement as its own query and reference both below:

```
SELECT i.*, (i.Store_Revenue / a.Store_Revenue) As Ratios
FROM
  Indiv_Item_StoreAggQ As i
INNER JOIN 
  All_Item_StoreAggQ  As a
ON i.FY = a.FY AND i.FW = a.FW AND i.Rept_Chnl = a.Rept_Chnl 
AND i.BU_NM = a.BU_NM AND i.Order_Store = a.Order_Store
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification Parfait and I appreciate the quick response!